# SQL server 2005 ENCRYPTBYKEY returns null

Tags: sql-server-2005, encryption

```
DECLARE @EmailEnc varbinary(maX)
declare @keyid uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @Email_test nvarchar(max)
set @Email_test = N'Sg@hotmail'
SELECT top 1 @keyid=[key_guid] FROM sys.symmetric_keys order by newid()
SET @EmailEnc=CAST(ENCRYPTBYKEY(@keyid,@Email_test) AS varbinary(max))
select @Email_test,@keyid,@EmailEnc
```

Results

---

Sg@hotmail                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       D790AE00-63FC-4BC5-8182-073BACDF1B12 
NULL
(1 row(s) affected)
Why Null ?? any ideas??

Answer (score 5):

You must "open" the key before using it.  An example is given in [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361(SQL.90).aspx) for how to do this.